# How to find all subdirectories with a specific name and delete its contents (and NOT delete the directories themselves)

Tags: linux

I can't seem to find a solution that works within several posts that seem to ask a similar question. This is the command that has come the closest to working which I've used as a test on test folders:

```
find . -iname "*Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews*" -exec sh -c 'rm -rf {}/*' \;
```

The problem is that `find . -iname "*Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews*"` by itself finds the subdirectories and prints them while `-exec sh -c 'rm -rf {}/*' \;` does the job of deleting only the contents without deleting the directory itself. But they do not work to find the directory and delete its contents when put together. What command should I use to accomplish those two tasks simultaneously?

Thanks

Comment: If I answered your question it would be nice if you would mark it accepted.

Comment: not working /: It's weird because if i use `find . -type d -iname "*Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews*" -print` it does find the right folders but the other part that removes the folders once it finds them doesn't work ):

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does it do anything at all? Do you have permissions to delete those folders? I have edited my script to add debug information. Please try again and let me know if the right folders appear. By the way, the script wont "remove the folders" - As you requested in your OP, it will only delete the contents, not the folder itself.

Comment: yes yes, sorry! You're correct, i didn't mean to say folders in my previous comment. Just the files in the folder. So I tried your updated script and it didn't delete the folders but it does find them. Here is the output after i execute the script:

Comment: `Deleting CONTENTS of folder: ./Vani copy/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews ./Vani copy/egwrg/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews ./Vani copy/Project 1/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews ./Vani copy/r/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews ./Vani copy 2/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews ./Vani copy 2/egwrg/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews ./Vani copy 2/Project 1/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews ./Vani copy 2/r/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews`

Comment: I wonder if I'm doing something wrong. So here are more details. I saved the script on my desktop. All the test folders I want it to find and delete the contents of are on my desktop as well. So i make sure i change to desktop as the current directory and then run `bash /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/deletepreviews.sh` on the terminal. Please let me know if there's something wrong with one of those things.

Comment: It seems correct. From the same folder you run the script in, can you run a `rm -rfv "./Vani copy/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews/*"`. It should say "Removed <file>" for every file. If that's the case please check if it worked. If it shows an error or something let me know please.

Comment: Did not work! So confused as to why! Nothing happens after I run that, nothing deleted and no output in terminal ):

Comment: Are you sure that the folder actually contains something? (`ls -lh "./Vani copy/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews/*"`)

Comment: It says it doesn't `ls: ./Vani copy/Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews/*: No such file or directory` but I know it has an .mov, a .png, and an after effects project

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of that? How do you check? It seems pretty much empty to me.

Comment: Well, it's very visible in the finder visually, so that's strange...I'm absolutely sure I see the files there

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    echo "Deleting CONTENTS of folder: $line"
    rm -rf "$line/*"
done <<< $(find . -type d -iname "*Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews*")
```

This loops through the results of find (Using `-type d` to only show directories so you won't run into problems if a file contains the search string) and performs an `rm -rf` on the contents of each result. The `/*` is important as without it it would delete the result directory too, instead of just its contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in `find . -type d -iname "*Adobe Premiere Pro Video Previews*"`; do
    find $dir -type f -delete
done
```

Comment: This will only delete *files* within the sub-directories. If I understood OP correctly he wants to delete everything within the found directories, just not the found directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be an expert in bash, but for me the following command is working :

`find . -iname "*test*" -type d -exec sh -c "rm -rf {}/*" \;`